# Trying to compile vim with python 3.6. Where is my config directory?

Tags: vimscript-python, installing, linux-ubuntu

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Linux, only started using it recently.

However, I am trying to compile vim with python because I  am using latex live preview and it needs a python compiled vim to work. I am following these steps here: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source

At part 3 it says to find your config for your python version such as `/usr/lib/python3.6/config`
I dont have that, I only have this: `_sysconfigdata_m_linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py`

Am I supposed to make a config directory, or should it already be there?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? 16.04 onwards has Vim with Python support in the repositories, and for older versions, you have PPAs. There's no need to manually build it.

Comment: `--with-python3-config-dir`, it tells you tight there in the link you posted xD

Comment: Any updates on this? I've been looking everywhere, I'm unable to locate the config file and thus compile with python3 support.

Answer (score 3):

Although not pretty sure, I guess you are on a x64 platform. The corresponding path is under /usr/lib64/pythonXX.

Comment: I found it via: find /usr -type d -name config

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while. My goal was to install VIM with python3 support in a Debian Buster docker container.

Try this:

1. `apt install -y vim-gtk python-pip python3-pip vim-common vim-gtk vim-gui-common vim-runtime gcc libc-dev make gettext ncurses-dev acl-dev`
2. `cd ~`
3. `git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git`
4. `cd vim/src`
5. `make distclean`  # if you build Vim before
6. `./configure --with-features=huge --enable-python3interp --enable-pythoninterp`
7. `make && make install`
8. `vim --version` #verify python and python3 have +

I had to play around with a few commands to uninstall vim when I was attempting this. You might find these helpful if you need to completely uninstall vim.

1. `apt purge vim`
2. `whereis vim`
3. `sudo rm <result-path-of-previous-command>`